# How to make apt ignore unfulfilled dependencies of installed package?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, dependencies

I installed Opera 12.16 from a `.deb` for reasons. Just assume that I need this specific browser of this specific version and that there’s no alternative.

However, that deb depends on packages (such as the gstreamer0.10 series) which are not in my distribution anymore (Debian testing). This makes apt fail on *every* operation except `apt remove opera` with dependency errors:

```
# apt install cli-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 opera : Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-good but it is not installable
         Recommends: flashplugin-nonfree but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

`apt --fix-broken install` will just propose to remove opera:

```
# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  opera
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 92 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 46.6 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Currently, my workaround is to install Opera when I need it, and remove it as soon as anything else needs to be done with apt. This is annoying.

Any suggestions? Ideally, I’d like to make apt ignore the dependencies of opera forever, since it works well-enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can’t make `apt` ignore dependencies, but you can create a fake `gstreamer0.10-plugins-good` package which will satisfy the missing dependency. The simplest way to do this is using [`equivs`](https://tracker.debian.org/equivs):

1. install `equivs`

   ```
   sudo apt install equivs
   ```
2. generate a template control file

   ```
   equivs-control gstreamer0.10-plugins-good.control
   ```
3. fix the package name

   ```
   sed -i 's/<package name; defaults to equivs-dummy>/gstreamer0.10-plugins-good/g' gstreamer0.10-plugins-good.control
   ```
4. build the package

   ```
   equivs-build gstreamer0.10-plugins-good.control
   ```
5. install it

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i gstreamer0.10-plugins-good_1.0_all.deb
   ```

That should satisfy the `opera` package’s dependency.

Comment: Does the `equivs` work anyway to solve the unmet dependencies (i mean when the `apt-cache` return nothing)?

Comment: @GAD3R I’m not sure what you mean. From the question, the only missing dependency is `Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-good but it is not installable` (the other is a Recommends which doesn’t matter). The commands I list above build an empty `gstreamer0.10-plugins-good` package which will satisfy the missing dependency without adding any of its own.

Comment: *Uninstalls opera to install equivs*. Thanks! That did the trick! I’m not even sad that if a package ``flashplugin-nonfree`` ever appears in the repositories, I won’t be able to install it until it passes 1.0 :-)

Comment: Howdy. In 2018 is this really still the only way to truly ignore dependencies in Apt? The internet is telling me it is, though.

Comment: @JDS yes, it is the only way. Dependencies are there for a reason, it shouldn’t be easy to ignore them.

Comment: This is brilliant. In my case, I'm using Ubuntu, which has a rather incomplete version of `nginx` — I have to compile my own. But this obviously leaves a 'hole' in the `apt` database, `apt` thinks that `nginx` is not installed (well... it's not on the database, that's for sure), so... `equivs` to the rescue! :-)

Comment: This worked great to create a fake package for `libappindicator3-1`, required by slack-desktop and signal-desktop .deb files but not actually required at runtime.

Answer (score 13):

You can also remove the `gstreamer0.10-plugins-good` dependency of the `opera` package by editing `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.

Just open it with a text editor, search for the line `Package: opera` and under it in the `Depends:` line remove the offending `gstreamer0.10-plugins-good`package.

After that `apt` works again.

Comment: ... until Opera gets updated, I presume? Then the status file ought to be changed... again.

Comment: This helped me just now for some other package which I am not maintaining.