# apt-get install does not find local library

Tags: apt, shared-library

After I tried to install `gstreamer1.0-rockchip1` and get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer1.0-rockchip1 : Depends: librockchip-mpp1 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I cloned, compiled and and installed the repository [mpp](https://github.com/rockchip-linux/mpp) with `make and sudo make install`. Now I have the needed libraries in `/usr/local/lib`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20 Aug  7 10:43 librockchip_vpu.so -> librockchip_vpu.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20 Aug  7 10:43 librockchip_vpu.so.1 -> librockchip_vpu.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20 Aug  7 10:43 librockchip_mpp.so -> librockchip_mpp.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20 Aug  7 10:43 librockchip_mpp.so.1 -> librockchip_mpp.so.0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Aug  7 10:43 pkgconfig
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    78944 Aug  7 10:20 librockchip_vpu.so.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1978352 Aug  7 10:20 librockchip_mpp.so.0
drwxrwsr-x 3 root staff    4096 Aug  7 09:01 ocaml
drwxrwsr-x 4 root staff    4096 Aug  7 08:58 python2.7
drwxrwsr-x 3 root staff    4096 Mar 11 02:17 python3.8
```

However, I still getting the same initial error. Is there a way to link the library?

My system:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gstreamer1.0-rockchip1` doesn't depend on a file called `/usr/local/lib/librockchip_mpp.so.1`, it depends on a package called `librockchip-mpp1` which may provide `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librockchip_mpp.so.1`.

Neither of these packages are available in `focal` repositories.

Normally, when an auxiliary repository (such as a PPA) provides a package, they should also provide any dependencies that aren't in the official repository.  It looks like your repo didn't do this.  It's also possible that you built `gstreamer-rockchip-1` from scratch yourself.

I tend to avoid diving into dependency hell and so I'd use an alternative, but if you want to go down the rabbit hole here's what you should do:

1. Look for a repository/PPA that supplies `gstreamer1.0-rockchip1` along with its dependencies, or
2. Package the dependencies yourself.

A search showed me two github repos of interest.  I don't know if this is where you got your package, or if these are the best forks of the packages, or if they work with each other, or if they contain any malicious code.  I'll let you decide all of that.

The first is a project which provides [`gstreamer-rockchip-1`](https://github.com/xiaoshzx/gstreamer-rockchip-1).  It looks like you already have a repository or `*.deb` from this project.  I took a look at the `debain/copyright` file and it doesn't point to any upstream projects.

I can see from `debian/control` that this package will depend on `librockchip-mpp`:

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), autotools-dev,
 librockchip-mpp-dev (>= 1.4.0), libx11-dev, libdrm-dev,
 libgstreamer1.0-dev, libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
```

The only dependency here that isn't available in `focal` is `librockchip-mpp1`.

Another search led me to a repository that provides [`librockchip-mpp{1,-dev}`](https://github.com/rockchip-linux/mpp) (or at least a package with that name).   This repository also provides the rules to package this package for debain-based distros, so this shouldn't be too tough.  This one also has a `debian/copyright` that points to itself, so it seems a little more legitimate.

When I look at its dependencies, it only has `debhelper, cmake` as its build dependencies.  It looks like we don't need to go deeper.

To build/install this package:

1. Choose a [tag](https://github.com/rockchip-linux/mpp/tags), and download its [tar.gz](https://github.com/rockchip-linux/mpp/archive/refs/tags/release_20171218.tar.gz). Then:

```
$ tar -xzf release_20171218.tar.gz
$ ln -s mpp-release_20171218.tar.gz mpp_1.4.0.orig.tar.gz
$ cd mpp-release_20171218
$ dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
$ sudo dpkg -i ../librockchip-mpp1_1.4.0-1_amd64.deb
```

Then you can continue the installation of `gstreamer1.0-rockchip1`.

Note, when I tried to compile this, I had some CMake configuration errors. Specifically:

> Could not find toolchain file: /etc/dpkg-cross/cmake/CMakeCross.txt

This is as far as I'm willing to pursue this thing.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for this explanation! Apart from answering the question,  it also adds very good related/how-to info. Thanks!

Comment: sorry. I'm getting the following error `dpkg-source: error: cannot fstat file ./mpp_1.4.0.orig.tar.gz: No such file or directory` when building with `dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us`

Comment: That means you missed the `ln` step in my instructions. You need to move, link, or copy the original tarball to `mpp_1.4.0.orig.tar.gz`.  `dpkg-buildpackage` will verify that the files you extracted match what is in that tarball.

Answer (score 0):

You can use equivs (as in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/404449/1215)) to create a phony package which satisfies the dependency. This is an alternative to *actually* packaging the library, which essentially tells the system "I took care of it, just believe me."