# Installing Ant is overriding Java Installation

Tags: ubuntu, java, ant

I am trying to install ANT after installing java. My java in Sun Java.

```
pc19@pc19-H110:~$  java -version
java version "20.0.2" 2023-07-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.2+9-78)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.2+9-78, mixed mode, sharing)
```

---

```
pc19@-H110:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-20/bin/java
```

---

```
pc19@pc19-H110:~$ whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-20/bin/java
```

---

```
pc19@-H110:~$ sudo apt-get install ant
```

---

```
pc19@-H110:~$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.20.1" 2023-08-24
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.20.1+1-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.20.1+1-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

When I install ANT using `sudo apt get install ant`, it is overring the Sun Java insallation with OpenJdk installation. Does anybody know the workaround for it?

Why is ant installation overriding java? How do I stop it?

Comment: How did you install Oracle Java?

Comment: I downloaded, unpacked and set the Java_HOME.

Answer (score 0):

The package manager is unaware of your Oracle Java installation. The `ant` package requires a JRE, and depends on either the `default-jre-headless` or the `java8-runtime-headless` package. As a result, installing `ant` installs the default JRE, which is OpenJDK 11 on Ubuntu 20.04 (`apt install ant` would tell you this). The JRE package reconfigures `/usr/bin/java`, and since that comes before your `jdk-20/bin` directory, `java` runs the system JRE rather than your JRE.

To avoid installing OpenJDK 11, you can tell your system that there is a headless JRE installed by creating a dummy `default-jre-headless` package; see [How to make apt ignore unfulfilled dependencies of installed package?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/404444/86440) for details, replacing `gstreamer0.10-plugins-good` with `default-jre-headless`.