Debian, how to tell apt to ignore a specific package it thinks is broken?
After installing the package xfce4-screensaver, apt and Synaptic keep telling me it's broken and sometimes even trying to automatically uninstall it. Because it has missing dependencies that it can't resolve because I'm on stable and, for whatever reason, it and some of its dependencies aren't in the stable repository. I just went and manually got the .deb for xfce4-screensaver from the testing repository and installed that, and even without those dependencies it's still working exactly as intended (or if there are actually parts of the program not functioning correctly because of this, then it's all stuff I was never going to use anyway) but it would be nice to get it to stop complaining every time I do almost anything with apt or dpkg
***@***:~/Downloads $ sudo dpkg -i xfce4-screensaver_4.18.3-1_arm64.deb 
(Reading database ... 602645 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack xfce4-screensaver_4.18.3-1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking xfce4-screensaver (4.18.3-1) over (4.18.3-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xfce4-screensaver:
 xfce4-screensaver depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.38.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.
 xfce4-screensaver depends on libgtk-3-0t64 (>= 3.21.4); however:
  Package libgtk-3-0t64 is not installed.
 xfce4-screensaver depends on libxfce4ui-2-0 (>= 4.18.4); however:
  Version of libxfce4ui-2-0:arm64 on system is 4.18.2-2.

dpkg: error processing package xfce4-screensaver (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.11.2-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xfce4-screensaver
***@***:~ $ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease                            
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease                                      
Hit:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm InRelease                   
Hit:5 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
***@***:~ $ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xfce4-screensaver : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.38.0) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libgtk-3-0t64 (>= 3.21.4) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libxfce4ui-2-0 (>= 4.18.4) but 4.18.2-2 is installed
                     Recommends: gir1.2-libxfce4util-1.0 but it is not installed
                     Recommends: gir1.2-xfconf-0 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
***@***:~ $ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xfce4-screensaver : Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.38.0) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libgtk-3-0t64 (>= 3.21.4) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libxfce4ui-2-0 (>= 4.18.4) but 4.18.2-2 is installed
                     Recommends: gir1.2-libxfce4util-1.0 but it is not installed
                     Recommends: gir1.2-xfconf-0 but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies



Does this answer your question? How to make apt ignore unfulfilled dependencies of installed package?

Unfortunately this can’t be completely handled with equivs (which is what the linked answer describes): the versioned dependency on libxfce4ui-2-0 can’t be fudged in that way.

I rolled back an edit that added a solution to the question text and a "(solved)" tag to the title.  If you have found a solution you'd like to contribute, please add a separate answer using the answer box at the bottom of this page.  You may later "accept" your answer if you wish.  Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

OP's solution is the same as https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/437223/70524 in the duplicate

You have tried to install a package from unstable/testing, where a lot of libraries are changing their binary interfaces, and are renamed with a t64 suffix as a result.
The t64 variants of these libraries are not available in the stable release.
I have tried to do a quick backport of xfce4-screensaver to Debian stable, but it requires a version of libxfce4ui that is only available in testing/unstable, so my expectation is that the entire xfce4 environment needs to be upgraded to allow for the installation of this package.
In short, the only way out for you at the moment is to uninstall xfce4-screensaver.
In the future, use a command like apt install ./xfce4-screensaver_4.18.3-1_arm64.deb (the ./ is important here to tell apt that you want to install a local file) to install packages -- this will pull in any required dependencies automatically, or refuse to install if it would leave you in an invalid state.

??? I said xfce4-screensaver works, that's not the problem. Or at least it works to blank the screen and make you enter your password to unlock it, which is all I need it to do

@cereallain Simon didn’t say anything about the screensaver not working. This addresses your question about apt: with xfce4-screensaver as it currently stands, the only way to get apt to stop complaining is to uninstall xfce4-screensaver.

well that's wrong because there's at least one way, finding the xfce4-screensaver entry in /var/libdpkg/status after its been installed and just removing the list of dependencies got it done

@cereallainWhile your "hack" worked in the short term, here's some food for thought:  Simon looks as if he is the Debian maintainer for the package you are trying to install, and I believe Stephen is a Debian Developer, so they know what they are talking about.  Let's say that Stephen finally either backports the needed library or the needed library goes from testing to stable.  Now the package you hacked moves to stable and gets a version bump.  Now, you're "hacky fix" won't allow the "fixed version" that Simon repaired to be installed because you manually intervened in APT's database... More

It's always better to let APT complain than to mess directly with the package database, as you've stated in your own answer.   I can almost guarantee the situation you  and I described here will happen, and I can also guess you don't have the dependency list that you removed saved somewhere.  Simon kindly explained that the issue was known and there are a plethora of other screenlockers, that a simple search would have turned up, namely xdg-screensaver, and Google's implementation which will serve as replacements, safer than messing with APT

alright I found a way around it. In /var/lib/dpkg/status after the package has been installed you can find the entry for the package in question and just delete its list of dependencies. Clumsy but it got apt to stop complaining. I foresee no problems as long as there is no package in the stable repository called xfce4-screensaver, and it shouldn't be difficult to revert these changes when/if it does get added to the stable repository. Until then apt isn't ever going to touch it anyway
